# How can I get the completed value of an async function when calling a function from index.js?

Tags: node.js, async-await, request-promise

I'm new to node and I'm trying to create a function to make API requests with pagination. The function successfully gives me the desired output, but I'm confused as to how I can use the .then() function in index.js as it's async. If I use await in my index.js then it throws an error. I hoping to get some guidance as to how I can fix this, and how I can understand async/await better.

```
//hs-api.js
const request = require('request-promise');
const settings = require('./settings');
var all = []

let getReq = async (url) => {  
    var options = {
        'method': 'GET',
        'url': url,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    let results = await request(options, function async (error, response) { 
        if (error) {
            reject(error)
        } else {
            res = JSON.parse(response.body)
        }
    })

    all = all.concat(res.results)

    if(res.hasOwnProperty("paging")) {
        await getReq(`${res.paging.next.link}&apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
    } else {
        console.log(all)
        return all
    }
}
```

Here is where I call the function

```
//index.js
let apiResponse = api.getReq(`https://apiexample.com/?apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
console.log(apiResponse)
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today (Node.js 14), you need to wrap it in a function.

Something like this

```
(async () => {
    let apiResponse = await api.getReq(`https://apiexample.com/?apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
    console.log(apiResponse)
})()
```

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) for ES for top-level `await` which will make it possible to run

```
let apiResponse = await api.getReq(`https://apiexample.com/?apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
console.log(apiResponse)
```

without wrapping it in an `async` function.

Node.js (since version 10) has an experimental support for this feature. You need to run it with `--experimental-repl-await` flag

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in async function in index.js.

```
    // index.js
    async someFn() {
        let apiResponse = await api.getReq(`https://apiexample.com/?apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
        console.log(apiResponse)
    }

   // call
   someFn();
```

or use '.then'

```
api.getReq(`https://apiexample.com/?apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
   .then(apiResponse => {
        console.log(apiResponse);
   })
   .catch(console.log);
```

**UPD:**

```
//hs-api.js
const results = await request(options);
// don`t sure, that it is correct error indicator for your library
if(result.error) {
    throw new Error(// describe error here);
}

const res = JSON.parse(response.body);
all = all.concat(res.results);

if(res.hasOwnProperty("paging")) {
    return await getReq(`${res.paging.next.link}&apikey=${settings.api_key}`)
} else {
    console.log(all);
    return all;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use both methods, but it returns 'undefined'.

Comment: @Yehudah ok, so your hs-api.js have not correct return statements. Check my update